# Chrome extension History API

Tags: tabs, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension that needs to analyze the recent browsing history *for a particular tab.* The [chrome.history API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html) allows me to search for items in the global history, but seemingly provides no means to localize the results to a particular tab. Am I missing something, or is this impossible to get?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking is the [navigation API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html). The Chrome history is not related to a particular tab. If you want to use or delete from the history a element of the tab navigation you can use the history search function with the navigation information.

Comment: link should be https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webNavigation/