# Remove all cookies for a tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to remove all data that belongs to a specific given tab in Chrome via my chrome extenstion.

For an example I would like to delete all the data (cookies, local storage, cache) set by a specific tab as seen in the below screenshot.

> [image]

So far I have found how to delete all the cookies but is there a way to clear all data stored by a tab via Chrome API?

Comment: When you are saying a specific tab, do you tab itself or its url?

Comment: @HaibaraAi I meant the tab itself. Let's say given the tab id.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to specifying a tab, I looked around the community and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13210877/6124253) that might be useful to you. It states:

*...the navigation API. The Chrome history is not related to a particular tab. If you want to use or **delete** from the history a element of the tab navigation you can use the history search function with the navigation information.*

Here's the link to the [Navigation API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) mentioned above.

I think you've already seen this (*since you mentioned you can already remove the cookies*), but I'm gonna go ahead and mention it, it might also be helpful. The [chrome.browsingData](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData) API has functions that when called remove specific types of browsing data, though it's not only specific to a single tab.